# For loop let scope stackblitz vs chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6, let

**Why does the following code produce a different result in StackBlitz vs Chrome Dev Tools?**

I would expect `i` to be `undefined` outside the `for` loop (agreeing with the Chrome Dev Tools result).

*What is going on here with the Stackblitz result?*

---

**Stackblitz (blank ES6 project)**

[image]

---

**Chrome Dev Tools**

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a question for Stackblitz... they probably transpile to ES5 and replace `let` with `var`, which would hoist the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackBlitz transpiles code to ES5, thus changing `let` to `var`. The latter is function-scoped, so it's visible outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for that. When you go on StackBlitz' website and click on new JavaScript project, the description states: *"Blank starter project for building **ES6** apps."*

Comment: Sure, thats because you write ES6. The transpilation process is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome you are running the native ES6 in your browser, Stackblitz is Babel compiling the ES6 down to ES5 and so the let would become a var. The var variable has scope in the whole block.

Comment: Thanks for that. When you go on StackBlitz' website and click on new JavaScript project, the description states: *"Blank starter project for building **ES6** apps."*

Comment: Building ES6 apps doesn't mean that they cannot be complied down to ES5 to run in browsers that don't natively support ES6.

Comment: I don't disagree. Just saying they could make that clearer.

Comment: You should have been getting a compiler error on referencing i outside of the for block.

Comment: Yes, I should have. But I didn't.

Comment: I suppose it is because an unscoped variable in JavaScript is valid JavaScript so the compiler allows it, if you run up a TypeScript project in StackBlitz it does cause a compiler error even though the code still compiles and logs the i.